# SQL Server - manually change UTC from DateTimeOffset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using DATEADD currently to add a time stored in minutes to a date stored in another table...

The Date in the table is:

```
CalendarDate = '27/08/2015'
```

I then add the Time to this date from another table [Staff.StartTime] which is stored in minutes.

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, Staff.StartTime, Calendar.Date) -- 540 Minutes (09:00:00)

--This would then show '27/08/2015 09:00:00'
```

The next step is I want to add the TimeZone to this date... This query below would SELECT the TimeZone correctly from yet another table [Requests.StartDate]

```
select 
RequestID,
DATEPART(TZ, Requests.StartDate) FROM Requests

--This would fetch back 60 (+ 01:00:00)
```

my Desired Result is to display the DATETIMEOFFSET like this:

```
'27/08/2015 09:00:00 + 01:00:00'
```

How can I achieve this... I have the elements but putting the correct syntax together is what is causing me the issue. I need something like this:

```
 DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(Staff.StartTime), Calendar.CalendarDate) +
 DATEPART(TZ, SUM(Requests.StartDate))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you give an example of "the UTC" and the result you expect when changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
SELECT 
SWITCHOFFSET (DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(e.StartTime) - 60, d.CalendarDate), DATEPART(TZ, (V.StartDate)))Start,
SWITCHOFFSET (DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(e.FinishTime) - 60, d.CalendarDate), DATEPART(TZ, (V.EndDate)))Finish,
```